# Moving single object around on touch and drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that is applied to several spheres in my scene. I would like to be able to move individual spheres around in the scene by holding them on the screen and dragging around. My first issue is that no matter which sphere you touch and drag, all the spheres move together (they are part of the same prefab but none of them are children of the other spheres). A second issue is that when you touch and drag anywhere on the screen the spheres react, instead of only reacting when you touch on one of the spheres.

```
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
            offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, screenPoint.z));
        } 
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, screenPoint.z);
            Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
            transform.position = cursorPosition;
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling that the issue of all the spheres moving together stems from the fact that the same script is applied to all the spheres, and `screenpoint` and `offest` are being derived from `gameObject.transform.position`, instead of the specific sphere that was touched. I have tried to fix this by putting the following code above the `for` loop, but I am guessing this might not even be the correct approach. I am new to this :).

```
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Physics.Raycast(touch.position, touch.position, out hit);
    if (hit.collider == GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Sphere0"))
    {
        selectedObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Sphere0");
    }
```

I have my tags set up properly, and if that worked for the first sphere (Sphere0) I would have written the code for the other spheres. But, it seems to not work at all. My project is an ARCore project, but I don't think that should change what I need to code for these aspects of the scene.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just want 1 master script separate from you spheres to do the raycasting on touch and sphere controlling. Then tag all your spheres with the same tag (ie. "sphere").

```
void Update()
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) // when screen is touched...
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Vector3.forward, out hit)) // ...cast a ray...
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "sphere") //...and check if ray hits a sphere
            {
                selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
            }
        }
    }

    // add touch controls here and apply to selectedObject for movement
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and happy new year! That sounds like it should work. I created an empty game object within the prefab that contains the spheres to hold my SphereMovementController script, which you can see here (too long for a comment): https://pastebin.com/V9REEN4p      
To my surprise, nothing happens when I touch and drag on any of the spheres now. Do you see any issue in my code or the way I described it's being set up?

Comment: try putting some Debug.Logs in different parts of the code and see which part it is not reaching. maybe the raycast needs to be tweaked - i did not try and test it.

Comment: What sound advice :) I have done so and changed my raycast to: `Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit)`. I then noticed that at the last line of code I am setting `transform.position = touchPosition;` but that is from when the script was on each sphere object, so now I changed it to `selectedObject.transform.position = touchPosition;` and the spheres move around when touched, but there are still issues.

Comment: Seems like once a sphere is selected it stays selected and I can't select other spheres by touching, and it may only be selecting a sphere if it is touched and also in the center of the screen. Additionally the spheres are on hinge joints, but this code allows them to move well outside the position/limits of the hinges. Lmk if you have any tips. I'll play around with it more and if I can't figure any of those out I will start some new questions. To give you more context/insight into the project, it's a system of hanging and swinging spheres the collide with each other in augmented reality :).